# How to send several instances of the vendor-specific options to a DHCP server using dhclient?

Tags: linux, dhcp, isc-dhcp, dhclient, dhcp-option

I need to send *vendor-options* to DHCP server using *dhclient (ISC)*.
I've added following lines in the *dhclient.conf*:

```
option dhcp6.vendor-class code 16 = {integer 32, integer 16, string};
send dhcp6.vendor-class <enterprise id> <string length> <string value>;
```

And it works.

Now, I need to send two different instances of this option. I've modified the *dhclient.conf*:

```
option dhcp6.vendor-class code 16 = {integer 32, integer 16, string};
send dhcp6.vendor-class <enterprise id1> <string length1> <string value1>;
send dhcp6.vendor-class <enterprise id2> <string length2> <string value2>;
```

But dhclient sends only the second one.
Is there valid way to send two different instances of the *vendor-options*?

Comment: On the same interface?

Comment: @DanilaLadner yes